# How to change a certain character in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to change/overwrite a certain character in my list of characters. So like, if I had a list that has a bunch of characters, I want to replace the first one, `someList[0]`, with some other character. I tried doing `someList[0] == "g"`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You should use a **single** equal sign, so `someList[0] = 'g'`.

Comment: Try `someList[0] = "g"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`=`, not `==` because `=` is an assignment operator and `==` is an equality operator

```
someList = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
someList[0] = "g"
print(someList)
```

Output:

```
['g', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Comment: Explain the difference between `=` and `==`

Comment: `=` is an assignment operator,
`==` is an equality operator

Comment: yes, I know that. I'm indicating to explain it in your answer to make it more complete. This will allow the question asker to actually understand why they were making this mistake.

Comment: Oh, I'm stupid. I had a bunch of different if and elif statements and I started writing it with ==.... lol Thanks!